# Accessing GET variables in Assemble.io

Tags: handlebars.js, assemble

I'm creating webpage using Assemble.io templating system and Grunt. Is there any way how can I access GET variables inside my .hbs tempates? I need to create a simple condition:

```
{{#if debug}}
<script src="path_to_script">
{{/if}}
```

And call this condition only in case of GET param `?debug=1` after current URL. Is it possible to access GET variables from .hbs templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with static site generator, since query string's value is available only at runtime.

However you can include the following code snippet into your .html page:

```
<script>
if (window.location.search.substring(1).split('&').indexOf('debug') > -1) {
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
        el = document.createElement('script');
    el.async = true;
    el.src = 'patth_to_script';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(el, s);
}
</script>
```

And when you open it in a browser `http://www.example.com/page?debug`, the required script will be loaded along with other scripts referenced on the page.